# What is the simplest way to overwrite the bits 10, 11, 12 of an unsigned int to X?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let `val` and `x` be 32-bit unsigned integers. Let `x` be in the range 0 til 8 (thus, holding at most 3 bits). What is the simplest way to overwrite the bits `10`, `11` and `12` of `val` to match the bits of `x`? I.e., in such a way that `(val >> 10) & 1 == x & 1`, `(val >> 11) & 1 == (x >> 1) & 1` and `(val >> 12) & 1 == (x >> 2) & 1`? As an example, this expression accomplishes this:

```
(val & ~(0x7 << 10)) | (x << 10)
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same with fewer operations?

Comment: `(~0x7 << 10)` doesn't do what you want. Use `~(0x7 << 10)` instead.

Comment: @ThomasJager oh, oops, thanks.

Comment: You can turn ~(0x07 << 10) into a literal, but a good compiler will likely do that anyway... I doubt you can do this better.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I could replace with `0b11111111111111111110001111111111`. I expect this to need 3 operations. I was just wondering if we can do it in two?

Comment: @MaiaVictor your compiler very probably replaces `~(0x07 << 10)` by a literal, you don't have to do yourself (you can check asking for the assembler)

Comment: Nope, the minimum is three operations. 1) clear the bits in `val`. 2) shift `x` so that the lsb of `x` is at bit 10. 3) OR `x` into `val`. Note that you could use bit fields to make the code look like a simple assignment, but if you examine the assembly, you'll see that the compiler is just doing those three steps for you.

Comment: Unless you've used a profiler to identify this line of code as a a bottleneck, you shouldn't worry about this kind of optimization.  It's not likely, as bitwise operations tend to be fast.

Comment: Okay, thank you all.

Comment: @user3386109: Intel's AVX-512F extensions include the VPTERNLOGD (and VPTERNLOGQ) operations, which can do a masked-blend in a single operation. However, getting the operands into place in order to use those opcodes would cost more than could be saved, unless you were planning on doing this operation over a vector. (You still have to shift `x`, though.)

Comment: @rici Yes, it figures that some processors will have specialized instructions for this. But as you say, the number of operations to use that specialized instruction on the AVX-512F is more than the three operations needed when **not** using that specialized instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you have is the simplest way (though I don't have a proof), assuming both `val` and `x` are variables rather than constants.  Any decent compiler will compute the constant value of `~(0x7 << 10)` at compile time, of course.

You might want to avoid the duplication by writing an (inline) function or macro if you need this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x` is `uint8_t` and val is `uint32_t`, then I would do this

```
val &= ~(0b111 << 10); // clear current value
val |= (x << 10);      // set new value
```

Generalizing as a function

```
void overwriteValue(uint32_t * val, uint8_t * x, uint8_t bit_shift, uint8_t bit_mask){
    *val &= ~(bit_mask << bit_shift);
    *val |= (*x << bit_shift);
}
```

Example:

```
uint32_t my_val = 0xafaf11af; //0b1010111110101111000 100 0110101111
                              //                bits 12, 11, 10
uint8_t x = 0x3;
uint8_t bs = 10;
uint8_t bm = 0x7;
overwriteValue(&my_val, &x, bs, bm);
//my_val = 0xafaf0daf
//0b1010111110101111000 011 0110101111
//                bits 12, 11, 10
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as the posted code, albeit with an intermediate store (which a compiler may just elide using the 'as if' rule).

Comment: Upvoting because other people may find this useful, but it is the same algorithm.